# How to determine a vector from a matrix corresponding to matching points of an affine function

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, rotation

I have a matrix `M` of size `NxN`.

I want to analyze parts of this matrix by slicing it into vectors passing through the center, and by rotation of `K` degrees.

For example this 5x5 matix :

```
 01 02 03 04 05
 06 07 08 09 10
 11 12 13 14 15
 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25
```

When K = 45°, I should have got this reuslt :

```
V = {21 17 13 09 05}
```

When K = 10°, I should have got something like this :

```
v = {22 18 13 08 04}
```

`N` can range from 100 to 1000
`K` can range from 0 to 90° by step of 1°

My first approach was to proceed to a matrix rotation and extract with a fixed vector column of index `(N/2,:)` by I failed to use a matrix rotation when N > 2, and the complexity is not good when `N` increase.

In the second time, I thought of discretize an affine function `f(x)=ax+b`, and find the minimum distance of each points compared to the points of the `M` matrix in order to establish my vector of coordinates.

The problem is still the complexity, more the matrix is big, more comparaisons I must to do for find the closest coordinates of each points of `f(x)`.

Do you have an optimized way to get a vector (or coordinates) from a matrix with a certain slope (angle) ?

Comment: You need to provide us with a small example of M (e.g., 5x5) and K and show us exactly what you want for outputs. E.g., What are the possible values of N and K?

Comment: I tried to use sub2ind function in matlab : 

M=zeros(200);
x=-1:0.01:1;
slope=0.30*x;
indexes=sub2ind(size(M), slope, x);

But i have an error using sub2ind. It tells me "Out of range subscript"